# sql query not working if come as a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to exec sql SP, and add a "select" to the query.
it is working fine, but if I add the "between" I get an error.

this is the code:

```
DECLARE @query as nvarchar(200);
    SET @query = N'select *
                    from (    
                    select *,totalRecords = COUNT(*) OVER(),ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY date desc) AS RowNum
                        from  #data
                    ) as RowConstrainedResult
                    where RowNum  between 1 and 20
                    ORDER BY RowNum';

    EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

and this is the error:

```
 Incorrect syntax near '1'.
```

Comment: @kzharas210 - which is exactly what `between` logically expands into. That should not be able to produce and logically different result.

Comment: Always, always, always. If you're having a dynamic SQL issue, your first step should be to `print @query` rather than `exec` and see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @query as nvarchar(200);
SET @query = 'select * from (select *,totalRecords = COUNT(*) OVER(),ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY date desc) AS RowNum from  #data) as RowConstrainedResult where RowNum between 1 and 20 ORDER BY RowNum';

  select @query              

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with the variable declaration

```
DECLARE @query as nvarchar(200);
                           ^^^
```

Since your variable contains multi line sql statement that is not enought for this variable, try to use MAX size variable for this multi line sql statement

```
DECLARE @query as nvarchar(MAX);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in `DECLARE @query as nvarchar(200);`

Change it to `DECLARE @query as nvarchar(MAX);`

You should `PRINT @query` to check your query before executing

Answer (score 0):

you have declared `@query as nvarchar(200)` and the query length is more than 200 so just change `@query as nvarchar(200)` to `@query as nvarchar(2000)` and it will work fine with you .